# SQL Server INSERT INTO TABLE from a JavaScript variable?

Tags: node.js, sql-server, db2

What I want to do is basically this:

```
let res = SELECT * FROM **some table on some DB2**

TRUNCATE **some table on SQL-Server DB**
BULK INESRT **some table on SQL-Server DB**
FROM res
...
```

Is that even possible? Is there a way to copy from one DB into another DB?

Comment: No, that isn't how SQL works.

Comment: @Larnu OK, I know that it's not possible like this obviously, but is there a way to achieve what I'm trying to achieve

Comment: If you want to do it directly in SQL [Server] you could use a `BULK` operation with `OPENROWSET`.

Comment: What has this (_"Is there a better way to copy from one DB into another DB?"_) to do with `javascript`? o.O

Comment: @Andreas There might be a way to do it programmatically with JavaScript and there might be a way to do it differently. What difference does it make? :)

Comment: I believe the OP was under the impression, @Andreas , that they could put the entirety of the table into a variable in Javascript and then reference that variable like it was a table in their T-SQL. Basically muxing the 3 languages/dialects into some hybrid.

Comment: _"What difference does it make?"_ - JS is executed in a browser (unless we talk about node then the tags are wrong again). Why should there be a way to manipulate a database through a client-only scripting language?

Comment: @Larnu That would just be another reason for a close vote...

Answer (score 1):

I think you have a bit of a misconception as to how SQL and JavaScript work. But, I'll provide an example of what you might be after.

If, indeed you are using SQL-Server and both databases are on the same server; then this will bypass any need for JavaScript (as long as not hosted by Azure or something similar):

```
SELECT *
INTO [DestinationDB].[DestinationSchema].[NonExistantTable]
FROM [SourceDB].[SourceSchema].[SourceTable];
```

That creates `[DestinationDB].[DestinationSchema].[NonExistantTable]` with the structure and data from `[SourceDB].[SourceSchema].[SourceTable]`

You can then do whatever you want with the original table as the data will still be there too.

Beyond that, I'm confused as to what you're after (and, more to the point, why you're after it).

Comment: hey, thanks for the comment. Let me clarify my question, is there a way to do this exact same thing, in some other way, assuming one table is in DB2 and the other is SQL Server?

Comment: Do you have code for grabbing data from the source table? If so, you're halfway there

Comment: Yes, of course :) I wonder about the other half though, what to do with the data grabbed from source table once I have it

Comment: If you can get data out; it's the same principle to put it back in